# Unable to add app.yaml in google cloud platform

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml

Recently I follow this guide : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql

However, I am stuck at step7

> Add the Cloud SQL instance connection name, database, user, and
>   password to the environment variables in app.yaml.

Where I app.yaml is located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide you're following is to setup and use Cloud SQL in a GAE app.

The `app.yaml` is the mandatory (part of) that GAE app's [configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref) and should be located in the directory from which later in the guide you will run your development server and deploy your application.

In the guide's code on github the file is [app.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/php55/cloudsql/app.yaml)